# Add private github repo as a dependency in package.json

Tags: git, github, npm

In my `package.json` I have a dependency linked to a private github repo:

```
"name-dep": "git@<token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com:<user>/<repo_name>.git"
```

Authentication works fine but in "node_modules", i don't have the expected "name-dep" folder, instead I found a *file* called "name-dep" and it's an *Alias* file type (on a Mac).

How can I fix this? Thanks